# How to reinitilize a plugin after a successful ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can you help me about this? I have some ajax function that will load the new information on my page every time the user scroll (means by reaching the bottom).

My problem is my plugin wont work on the new data.

Here's my code:

On the initial load I have some kind of code here. This will call the plugin.

```
<div class="thumb_container">
    <div class="thumbnailer">
        <img data-src="{{ clip.video_thumbnail }}" class="img-responsive lazy {{ (clip.youtube_video != '') ? 'js-modal-btn' : '' }}"  data-video-id="{{ clip.youtube_video }}" style="width: 90px; height: 90px; padding: 3px 15px;" />
    </div>
    <span class="textlabel js-modal-btn" data-video-id="{{ clip.youtube_video }}">Watch the movie</span>
</div>
```

When the user **CLICK** the label **Watch the movie** that has a class of **js-modal-btn** it will call my plugin

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
    $('.js-modal-btn').modalVideo(); //initial load OK
});
```

Then if the user reach the bottom I will call my function that has an ajax process that will add new information.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        loadVideoData();
    }
});

function loadVideoData() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=common/home/loadMoreVideo',
        type: 'post',
        data: { row: row },
        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#loadtext").fadeIn().delay(5000);
        },
        success: function() {
            //add new stuff here
            $('.js-modal-btn').modalVideo(); //called again my plugin (WONT WORK)
        }
    });

}
```

can you help me with this?

Comment: This is not [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are lots of reasons why the code won't work. You need to provide more details

Comment: @Adelin ok I will update my code. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: The most relevant part is still missing. What is the content of `modalVideo`? I guess `success` callback is called, right? Then so is `modalVideo`, but it doesn't do its job. Let us see what its job is.